# Finding the surface area

Tags: geometry

[image]

What I tried doing is by using the formula and adding it all together.

I managed to find the first picture far left but the other two not.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: surface area of a cone is $A=\pi r(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2})$

Comment: surface area of a sphere is $A = 4\pi r^2$

Comment: I used the formula that I was given by my teacher. First picture far left. 2*pi*1^2+2*pi*1*1 = 12.56m^2,,,, 2*pi*1^2/2 = 3.14m^2 , 12.56+3.14 = 15.7m^2. Second: same formula = 12.56m^2 ,,, pi*1^2+pi*1*1 = 6.28m^2,, 12.56+6.28 = invalid. third picture: 2*pi*1^2/2 = 3.14m^2 ,,, pi*1^2+pi*1*1 = 6.28m^2, ,, 3.14 + 6.28 = invalid. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

For the middle figure, surface area=(surface area of cone) - (area of circle)+(surface area of right cyliner)-(area of circle)

$$A=\pi r(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2})-(\pi r^2) + (2\pi rh+2\pi r^2)-(\pi r^2)$$

here $r=1, h=1$

$$A=\pi(1+\sqrt{2})+2\pi=\pi(1+\sqrt2+2)=\pi(3+\sqrt2)$$

For the third figure,

A=(surface area of sphere/2)+(surface area of a cone)-(area of a circle)

$$A=\frac{4\pi r^2}{2}+\pi r(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2})-(\pi r^2)$$

here $r=1, h=1$

$$A=2\pi+\pi(1+\sqrt2)-\pi=\pi+\pi(1+\sqrt2)=\pi(2+\sqrt2)$$

Comment: I will look at this after I come home.

Comment: @heeelp, As you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

The area of the curved surface of the cone in in the right two bodies can be get by integration:

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{1\text m} dr \frac{\sqrt{h^2+r^2}}{r} r = \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{1\text m} dr \sqrt2 r  = \sqrt2\pi \text m^2$$

The factor $\sqrt2$ can be obtained by the Phythagoras and the fact that the radius and height has the same value, 1m.

Comment: I think we he/she is asking as an precalculus student as he/she didn't put the calculus tag. I think it's safe to assume that he/she can implement the surface area and volume formulae without proving them.

Answer (score 0):

A cone of radius r and slant height L has surface area $ \pi r L. $ Here $  r=1, L= \sqrt 2. $